# dependency libviso2 cannot be found

Tags: ros, rosdep, rosdep-install, ros-fuerte, libviso2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working with ROS-Fuerte and eclipse. I want to make a package with the next dependencies

anjinsan@Erasmus:~/fuerte_workspace$ roscreate-pkg odometria roscpp std_msgs sensor_msgs opencv2 cv_bridge image_transport tf geometry_msgs image_geometry libviso2 message_filters nav_msgs pcl_ros std_srvs ros

and I get the next message

ERROR: dependency [libviso2] cannot be found

So i've tried to install it...

anjinsan@Erasmus:~/fuerte_workspace$ rosdep install libviso2

ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource libviso2
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/ellian/fuerte_workspace
ROS path [2]=/home/ellian/fuerte_workspace/sandbox
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [5]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros

What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68977/dependency-libviso2-cannot-be-found/) by [Ellian Herrera](https://answers.ros.org/users/5491/ellian-herrera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[libviso2](http://www.ros.org/wiki/viso2) is not a binary or library that can be solved with a rosdep dependency. You can download and compile from [Github] a wrapper for ROS (https://github.com/srv/viso2) and work as if libviso2 was a ROS package.

In your ROS workspace type (you should have followed the [tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment) about the rosws tool):

```
rosws set viso2 --git 'https://github.com/srv/viso2.git'
rosws update viso2
cd viso2
git checkout fuerte
rosmake
```

and then you are ready!

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2013-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ellian Herrera](https://answers.ros.org/users/5491/ellian-herrera/) on 2013-07-26**:
I'm new working with ROS.
I've downloaded the folder, I'm not sure of what I have to do.
Should I paste the folder "viso2_fuerte" in /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks and then run "make" in a terminal?